# RTP distribution gateway in golang

Tags: go, media, rtp

I am writing a media gateway for a calling application. It doesn't need to process the RTP in any way and hence it just receives RTP (from the caller) on a UDP socket and sends to other members in the conference call. So I am using a simple `for` loop to do the job. But the gateway is unable to cope with heavy loads (more number of members in the call) and there is an increase in latency. Are there any alogrithms/techniques to increase the efficiency of this? If there is any good library in golang, that is also welcome.

Comment: There's not enough information in the question for an accurate answer. We don't know where the bottlenecks are in your program, and there's not a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are an abundance of techniques to improve efficiency, but without profiling nothing can be recommended. Do you have pprof results that could help your case? "Heavy loads" is very generic.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with profiling in Go, this talk by Dave Cheney is a good starting point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nok0aYiGiYA

Comment: Thank you. Will go through above video and update the resuts. Also, I will try to include it minimum reproducible example.